# Why am I not getting representations for both product and customer nodes (heterogenous graph)?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dgl

I have the following graph:

cust_prod_graph is

```
Graph(num_nodes={‘customer’: 8813, ‘product’: 157466},
num_edges={(‘customer’, ‘browsed’, ‘product’): 860771, (‘customer’, ‘purchased’, ‘product’): 68367},
metagraph=[(‘customer’, ‘product’, ‘browsed’), (‘customer’, ‘product’, ‘purchased’)])
```

with both types of nodes having 5641 features.

I have the following code:

```
cust_feats = cust_prod_graph.nodes[‘customer’].data[‘cust_features’]
prod_feats = cust_prod_graph.nodes[‘product’].data[‘prod_features’]

node_features = {‘customer’: cust_feats, ‘product’: prod_feats}
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters()).
rel_names = cust_prod_graph.etypes
conv1 = dglnn.HeteroGraphConv({
rel: dglnn.GraphConv(n_features, 32).double()for rel in rel_names}, aggregate=‘sum’)
```

architecture of conv1 is

```
HeteroGraphConv(
(mods): ModuleDict(
(browsed): GraphConv(in=5641, out=32, normalization=both, activation=None)
(purchased): GraphConv(in=5641, out=32, normalization=both, activation=None)
)
)
```

with `conv1(cust_prod_graph,node_features)` , I expect the embeddings of both product and graph nodes. However, my output looks like the following:

```
{‘product’: tensor([[ 12.9467, -8.6195, 11.2425, …, -14.4359, -68.9401,
-82.6712],
[ -7.5036, 15.4040, -75.5001, …, 28.9520, -148.9352,
-115.1991],
[ 166.8621, -45.5309, 379.8224, …, -249.0713, -37.2838,
-284.1231],
…,
[ -16.6725, 43.8654, 2.4352, …, 28.1842, -21.5894,
-12.7247],
[ -1.2243, 3.8499, -14.4112, …, 7.8305, -72.1459,
-70.6307],
[ 2.6126, -4.0843, -6.6758, …, -1.8361, -42.6932,
-46.4625]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=)}.
```

I do not see the customer node representations. What am I doing wrong?